# Execute prelogin scripts for SSH

Tags: 14.04, command-line, server, bash, openssh

I would like to know how I can execute a local server script, for instance send a mail using mailx, when a ssh session is opened, pre-login stage.

*When a ssh connection comes into the server, I would like to action a script pre-login.*

**example...**

```
Client_SSH >> **{server_script_exec}** >> login_prompt  >> Server       [login failed]
```

I have tried searching for this, but I only seem to get scripts that execute after login, like through `.bashrc`

I know I'm opening myself up to some flooding, however I would like to learn about the pre-login process. The server is in a controlled environment, and not exposed to the www.

Comment: see the `sshd_config` man page and the `ForceCommand`. Get it to run your script which should end with $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [PAM](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man7/pam.7.html) for this. The PAM configuration for the SSH service is in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`. To run a command before anything in the login process, add something like:

```
auth [default=ignore] pam_exec.so /path/to/some/script
```

For example, if I use `/usr/local/bin/foo.sh` containing:

```sh
#! /bin/sh

cat <<EOF >>/tmp/log
PAM_RHOST $PAM_RHOST  
PAM_RUSER $PAM_RUSER  
PAM_SERVICE $PAM_SERVICE  
PAM_TTY $PAM_TTY  
PAM_USER $PAM_USER  
PAM_TYPE $PAM_TYPE  
EOF
```

And then I do `ssh muru@localhost`, I get:

```
$ cat /tmp/log
PAM_RHOST localhost
PAM_RUSER
PAM_SERVICE sshd
PAM_TTY ssh
PAM_USER muru
PAM_TYPE auth
```

This doesn't happen before the password prompt shows up, but `auth` modules are the first ones run after the password is entered - they check whether the user is authenticated, after all:

```
   authentication - authenticate a user and set up user credentials.
   Typically this is via some challenge-response request that the user
   must satisfy: if you are who you claim to be please enter your
   password. Not all authentications are of this type, there exist
   hardware based authentication schemes (such as the use of smart-cards
   and biometric devices), with suitable modules, these may be substituted
   seamlessly for more standard approaches to authentication - such is the
   flexibility of Linux-PAM.
```

So, in effect, `auth` modules run before login, and if the first `auth` module is [`pam_exec`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/pam_exec.8.html), that's pretty much the first thing to run.

Note the `[default=ignore]` part - since `auth` modules authenticate the user, we don't want the script's exit status to mean anything. `default=ignore` tells PAM to ignore `pam_exec`'s return value, whatever it may be, which in turn depends on the script's exit status. See [`man pam.d`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/pam.d.5.html) for more details.

Caveats:

- This doesn't run if the user just quit before entering any password.
- This doesn't run if the user provided an *empty* password (the default SSH configuration has `PermitEmptyPasswords no`, so SSH rejects those out of hand).
- SSH needs to have `UsePAM yes` for it to use PAM.

Comment: Just wanted to add that on Ubuntu 18.04.03, the `session` /etc/pam.d/sshd entry worked, not `auth`:  `session [default=ignore] pam_exec.so /path/to/my/script.sh`

Comment: @AnythingIsFine I don't think the `session` entry will run *before* the login prompt, but if it works... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯